# Generate dropdown List in JavaScript (unknown mistake)

Tags: javascript

I want to regenerate **List2** (selSortt) everytime the user changes the selection in **List1** (selQueryType). In its original state, **List2** is **blank**. Both lists are part of a larger HTML input document. **List1** has 4 options, so in the end there will be 4 ifs - actually a `switch`. **List 2** is generated from a predefined array (**listvalues**), NOT from **List1** (see code).

`Function QueryTypeChg()` is fired by `onchange` List1 - I checked with an alert, it is fired. The problem seems to be in the `for` cycle, when trying to generate the new options of List2. **No options are added** to List2 - it remains blank, as it is originally.

```
function QueryTypeChg()
{
var selIndex = document.getElementById("selQueryType").selectedIndex;

var objSel = document.getElementById("selSortt");
var i = 0;

while (objSel.length > 0)
   {
   objSel.remove(0);
   }

if (selIndex == 0)
   {
   var listvalues = ["Species", "Region, area", "Anthesis", "Vulnerability"];

   for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) 
       {
       var option = document.createElement("option");
       option.text = listvalues[i];
       option.value = i;       
//       alert("option.text is " + option.text);
       objSel.add(option);
       }​
   }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are [removing the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) by doing

```
while (objSel.length > 0)
{
  objSel.remove(0);
}
```

If you want to clear the select then simply replace this while loop with

```
objSel.innerHTML = "";
```

Complete code should be

```
function QueryTypeChg()
{
  document.getElementById("selSortt").innerHTML = document.getElementById("selQueryType").innerHTML 
  document.getElementById("selSortt").selectedIndex = document.getElementById("selQueryType").selectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: @RayonDabre remove is removing that element from its DOM Tree, please check the document link attached

Comment: OP wants to remove all the options and then add new options to the select.. What is wrong with the code he has written ? `innerHTML = ""` could be another approach but why do we need it ?

Comment: I assumed that by doing `remove(0)` he intended to remove the child but instead he ended up removing the element itself. I have posted another much simpler approach.

Comment: The `remove()` method is taken from W3Schools, which says it is the opposite of `add()` - adding an option to a list. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp. As I clearly stated, I just want to re-generate the list, not to remove it from the document. But this is secondary; in the original state, the list is EMPTY, and my code DOES NOT add new options to the list from array **listvalues**. This is for now my problem. :)

Comment: @Mikey Check the link I have shared, it removes the current node from DOM tree. Did you tried the code I have shared?

Comment: I answered - removing the object IS NOT my main problem AND IT DOESN'T HAPPEN - since the list, in its original form, is empty, and the while cycle IS NOT ENTERED.

Comment: @Mikey In that case, do elaborate on `The problem seems to be in the for cycle` Do you see any error on the console? what output do you see>

Comment: I cannot see my script in Mozilla Debugger - it doesn't appear in the scripts list. But when I remove the `for cycle` from the script (the generation part for List2), it works OK.

Comment: @gurvinder372 This script is actually only a fragment of my script, which is much larger, since my HTML Form has 8 controls, which work quite well. The generation of "List2" (which actually is List6 :)) is the LAST thing I want to do in this form !

Answer (score 0):

You have use **options** variable instead of **listvalues**
please change below code which might help you

```
 for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
```

with

```
for (i = 0; i < listvalues.length; i++)
```

Comment: True, but this is not the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I "nailed" it with the following code:

```
function QueryTypeChg()
{
var selIndex = document.getElementById("listQueryType").selectedIndex;
localStorage.setItem("QueryType", selIndex);

if (selIndex == 0)
   {
   var listvalues = ["Species", "Region, area", "Anthesis", "Vulnerability"];
   var str_options = '';

   for (var i=0; i < listvalues.length; i++)
       {
       str_options += "<option value='" + [i] + "'>" + listvalues[i] + "</option> \r\n";
       }

   $("#listSort").html("");
   $("#listSort").append(str_options);
   return;
   }

}
```

I still don't know why it didn't work with the initial code. It DOES work in the W3Schools Try It window and in other examples I've seen. What's also peculiar is that it uses the `html()` method, not the `innerHTML` property. What kind of all-over-the-place language is this JavaScript anyway? In Pascal there is always ONLY ONE WAY to do a certain thing!